# Windows 10 Pro bluescreens during Windows update (Windows 1803)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bsod

Been having a recurring issue for months now where I cannot update my Windows 10 Pro N machine. It blue screens through the process and then when Windows restarts and attempts to repair it freezes around 44%.

Inside `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther` there are the follow errors:

```
2019-10-25 20:07:34, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to set WU internal configuration property for targeted scans. hr = 0x80070057
2019-10-25 20:08:02, Error                 CONX   0xd0000034 Failed to add user mode driver [%SystemRoot%\system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\uicciso.dll]

2019-10-25 20:10:27, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2019-10-25 20:11:14, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #92579# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216, status = '(null)', value = { type: 40972, bytes ( 12 ): 65006e002d00550053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-10-25 20:11:58, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2019-10-25 20:17:36, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2019-10-25 20:17:36, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
```

I've a feeling something has gotten corrupted, but it could also be the weird way N editions need to have media packs installed but I'm at a loss. I am certain it's because it's N editon.

Has anyone came across this before?

Comment: Edit your question to specify what feature update your trying to install.  I have only see this error when the system was on an unsupported version of Windows 10 being installed to a supported version.  In the specific case it was 1507 to 1803.

Comment: Got it fixed, motherboard needed a bios update. What should I do with this question?

Comment: Write a detailed answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the BIOS and Windows update worked fine.

Keep in mind updating the BIOS is a process that can render your machine inoperable. Only update your BIOS if you've taken appropriate backups and know what you're doing. Failed updates can result in an unuseable computer.